# How to set timezone and locale on a Wildfly Docker image?

Tags: docker, jboss, centos, dockerfile, wildfly

[The official Wildfly image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly) available on Docker Hub has the timezone set as UTC and no locale configuration present.

The image has the following dependency tree:

```
jboss/wildfly
└── jboss/base-jdk:11
    └── jboss/base
        └── centos:7
```

Based on that, I checked the timezone/locale configuration using the following commands:

```
docker exec -t <id> locale
docker exec -t <id> cat /etc/localtime
```

How can I set the appropriate timezone and locale information on a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with after checking the base images’ Dockerfiles and CentOS docs:

The following Dockerfile sample sets the São Paulo, Brazil timezone and Brazilian Portuguese as the locale, one can change the timezone/locale to fit one's needs:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.1.0.Final

USER root

RUN localedef -i pt_BR -f UTF-8 pt_BR.UTF-8
RUN echo "LANG=\"pt_BR.UTF-8\"" > /etc/locale.conf
RUN ln -s -f /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime

USER jboss

ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I most cases you can adjust language and timezone with the standard Linux environment variables TZ, LANG and LANGUAGE. See the following example:

```
docker run -e TZ="America/Sao_Paulo" \
   -e LANG="pt_BR.UTF-8" \
   -e LANGUAGE="pt_BR.UTF-8" \
   -e LC_ALL="pt_BR.UTF-8" \
   -it jboss/wildfly
```

This will change language and timezone during runtime. If you want to change the language and timezone in general you can also change the Dockerfile like mentioned by Fábio